# Cordova/Phonegap geolocation plugin manage error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I'm writing an Cordova/Phonegap app and I use a Geolocation plugin...this is my code...

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;

    console.log("Latitude: "+position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude: "+position.coords.longitude);
};

function onError(error) {
    logService.debug("Code: "+error.code);
    logService.debug("Message: "+error.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Now, I test it on browser and when I don't the permission I receive Error code 1 (PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED), when I do the permission it works very well on browser...Now born che question...When I test this on device and the GPS is off I don't receive the Error code 1 (PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED) but receive always timeout...in this way I don't discern the difference...I set the timeout to 150000 but I receive always code 3 (PositionError.TIMEOUT)...Why? How can use it in the rigth way?

Comment: what do you want actually when the device`s gps is off ? let the user to turn on it ?

Comment: I want to read in my console...code 1 (PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED) or code 2 (PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE)...it mustn't always timeout...

Comment: even if the GPS is turned off, it should be able to get the position from the 3G network, wifi, etc. Anyway, geolocation plugin uses the native webview built in geolocation, so blame google (by blame I really mean, open an issue on the android issue tracker)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the handling of the geolcation errors to be platform-specific. Since setting `enableHighAccuracy: true` causes your app to ask the OS retreive a position using the GPS hardware, the effect of turning off GPS on an Android device varies depending on the Android version: either the OS is never able to retreive a high-accuracy position, so the TIMEOUT error occurs (PERMISSION_DENIED will not be received on Android) or a low accuracy position will be retrieved and passed instead using Wifi/cell triangulation.

I'd suggest using `watchPosition()` instead of `getCurrentPosition()` to retrieve the location; getCurrentPosition() makes a single request for the device position at that current point in time, so the position timeout may occur before the GPS hardware on the device has had a chance to get a position fix, whereas using `watchPosition()` you can setup a watcher which will call the success function each time the OS receives a location update from the GPS hardware. If you only want a single location, clear the watcher after receiving a position of sufficient accuracy. If GPS is turned off on the Android device when the watcher is added, it will continue to return a TIMEOUT error; my workaround for this is to clear and re-add the watcher after a number of consequetive errors.

So try something along these lines:

```
var MAX_POSITION_ERRORS_BEFORE_RESET = 3,
MIN_ACCURACY_IN_METRES = 20,
positionWatchId = null, 
watchpositionErrorCount = 0,
options = {
    maximumAge: 60000, 
    timeout: 15000, 
    enableHighAccuracy: true
};

function addWatch(){
    positionWatchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onWatchPositionSuccess, onWatchPositionError, options);
}

function clearWatch(){
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionWatchId);
}

function onWatchPositionSuccess(position) {
    watchpositionErrorCount = 0;

    // Reject if accuracy is not sufficient
    if(position.coords.accuracy > MIN_ACCURACY_IN_METRES){
      return;        
    }

    // If only single position is required, clear watcher
    clearWatch();

    // Do something with position
    var lat = position.coords.latitude,   
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
}


function onWatchPositionError(err) {
    watchpositionErrorCount++;
    if (watchpositionErrorCount >= MAX_POSITION_ERRORS_BEFORE_RESET) {        
        clearWatch();
        addWatch();
        watchpositionErrorCount = 0;
    }

}
addWatch();
```